# ActivityResultLauncher for 3 activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, registerforactivityresult

I have 3 activities.

The first activity is a map (using Google Map API). In this activity, I also have a button that will direct to second activity.

In Second activity, it's just for additional information but there is a button. When this button is clicked, it will be directed to third activity.

In third activity, there's only a button that will bring a result to first activity (maps).

This is how I assigned my first activity's button:

```
startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
```

And I also used ActivityResultLauncher in first activity like so:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> intentLaunch = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if(result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                    String data = result.getData().getStringExtra("SIMPAN");
                    Log.d(TAG, "berhasil");
                }
            }
    );
```

In my third activity's button, I assigned it like this:

```
third_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("SIMPAN", "Simpan");
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(ThirdActivity.this, FirstActivity.class)); // When the button is clicked, it will get back to first activity and bringing the result
        }
    });
```

But, turns out the first activity didn't get the result. I assume that I missing this particular code after using ActivityResultLauncher:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
    intentLaunch.launch(intent);
```

However, it makes the application starts from third activity instead of first activity. It does receive the result (the log was showing) but it's only one time. How can I resolve this?

*(Sorry for my bad english)*

Answer (score 0):

This is an overkill.
Simply:

`Intent intent = getIntent();`

`String simpan = intent.getStringExtra("SIMPAN");`

in your `onCreate class`

`registerForActivityResult` is used when you get a result from outside the app, such as getting a picture from the camera.